# Find similar entries using pig script

Tags: apache-pig

I have data as below

```
1,ref1,1200,USD,CR  
2,ref1,1200,USD,DR  
3,ref2,2100,USD,DR  
4,ref2,800,USD,CR  
5,ref2,700,USD,CR  
6,ref2,600,USD,CR
```

I want to group these records where field2 matches, sum(field3) matches and field5 is opposite (means if lhs is "CR" then rhs should be "DR" and viceversa)

How can I achieve this using pig script?

Comment: Could you give an example of summing field3? Also, I'm assuming the final groups are pairs (because field5 has to be opposite).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do it this way:

```
data = LOAD 'myData' USING PigStorage(',') AS
       (field1: int, field2: chararray,
        field3: int, field4: chararray,
        field5: chararray) ;

B = FOREACH (GROUP data BY (field2, field5)) GENERATE group.field2, data ;

-- Since in B there will always be two sets of field2 (one for CR and one for DR)
-- grouping by field2 again will get all pairs of CR and DR
-- (where the sums are equal of course)
C = GROUP B BY (field2, SUM(field3)) ;
```

The schema and output at the last step:

```
C: {group: (field2: chararray,long),B: {(field2: chararray,data: {(field1: int,field2: chararray,field3: int,field4: chararray,field5: chararray)})}}
((ref1,1200),{(ref1,{(1,ref1,1200,USD,CR)}),(ref1,{(2,ref1,1200,USD,DR)})})
((ref2,2100),{(ref2,{(4,ref2,800,USD,CR),(5,ref2,700,USD,CR),(6,ref2,600,USD,CR)}),(ref2,{(3,ref2,2100,USD,DR)})})
```

The output put is a little unwieldy right now, but this will clear it up:

```
 -- Make sure to look at the schema for C above
 D = FOREACH C { 
        -- B is a bag containing tuples in the form: B: {(field2, data)}  
        -- What we want is to just extract out the data field and nothing else
        -- so we can go over each tuple in the bag and pull out
        -- the second element (the data we want).                     
        justbag = FOREACH B GENERATE FLATTEN($1) ;  
        -- Without FLATTEN the schema for justbag would be:
        -- justbag: {(data: (field1, ...))}  
        -- FLATTEN makes it easier to access the fields by removing data:
        -- justbag: {(field1, ...)}
        GENERATE justbag ;                                                  
 }
```

Into this:

```
D: {justbag: {(data::field1: int,data::field2: chararray,data::field3: int,data::field4: chararray,data::field5: chararray)}}
({(1,ref1,1200,USD,CR),(2,ref1,1200,USD,DR)})
({(4,ref2,800,USD,CR),(5,ref2,700,USD,CR),(6,ref2,600,USD,CR),(3,ref2,2100,USD,DR)})
```

Comment: Thank you. Will try this and let you know if that is giving the desired result.

Comment: Yes it worked. This is what exactly I was looking for, thank you so much. But could you please clarify me the part where you are calculating "D". What does it exactly do?

Comment: Doing a FOREACH over a bag creates a new bag, and the new bag has the data formatted in a way that makes it easier to use. See the comments I added to the code for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand your requirements, but you could load the data, split into two sets (filter/split) and the cogroup such as:

```
data = load ... as (field1: int, field2: chararray, field3: int, field4: chararray, field5: chararray);

crs= filter data by field5='CR';
crs_grp = group crs by field1;
crs_agg = foreach crs_grp generate group.field1 as field1, sum(crs.field3);
drs = filter data by field5='DR';
drs_grp = group drs by field1;
drs_agg = foreach drs_grp generate group.field1 as field1, sum(drs.field3);
g = COGROUP crs_agg BY (field1, field3), drs_agg BY (field1, field3);
```

Comment: Thanks Neumann.Yes that's the start point.After this I need to sum up field3 pertaining to same field2 but with opposite indicator in field5. Then group together all such records where the sums equal.

Comment: In fact the result I need is - group records 1 & 2 as one set and group records 3,4,5 & 6 into another set.

Comment: ok, I think I understand  -so you'd to filter, then group and calculate the sum, and then cogroup, see in answer, formatted as code.